# Adding floating point to the integer

Tags: c, double, zero, fractions

i need help with my homework, i need to make a c program that gets a double
and prints the number without the floating point for example
gets 157.89943912 and prints 15789943912

so i made this

```
    void main()
    {
        double x = 157.89943912; 
        while (x - (int)x > 0.0000001)
        {
            x *= 10;
        }
        printf("%lf", x);

        scanf_s("%d");

    }
```

now because of double zero inaccuracy the loop runs forever
but if i put 157.8994391 (one less floating point decimal)
it works..

thanks in advance!.

Comment: would it be cheating to `sprintf()` the `double` and then remove the "." from the string?

Comment: Your problem is about floating point computing error, you wrongly suppose 157.89943912 * 10 is 1578.9943912 etc, this is not the case

Comment: @bruno not really: 15789943912 might not be representable as an `int` (it needs at least 5 bytes) so tha cast will overflow

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes, also

Comment: `scanf_s("%d");` ? ouppps

Comment: This is actually a much harder problem than it looks, because numbers like 157.89943912 are *not* represented internally as `157.89943912`.  An infinite loop is exactly what I'd suspect; it's arguably the correct result for this ill-defined problem. You're going to need to ask for a better definition of how many of the fractional digits to use.  (You might be able to get away with breaking out of your loop after you see three 0's in a row, or something.)

Comment: What should it print if the input was 157.899439120000010916555766016?

Comment: It's limited to 10 digits after the floating point